# Is there a way to defined return type based on the parameter array?

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a function type definition that would use function parameter value types to create a union type for a return value.

For example, if we have a configuration that we want to enhance with an additional parameter.

```
type A = string
type B = string
type C = string

type Config = {
    a: A
    b: B
    c: C
}

type D = string
type DConfig = {
    d: D
}

type AdditionalConfig<T> = T & DConfig

type AddAdditionConfig<T, K extends keyof T> = T extends infer U
  ? {
      [a in keyof U]: a extends K ?   AdditionalConfig<U[a]> : U[a]
    }
  : never

const config: Config = {a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'}
```

Based on that I can create a function that takes the config and produces a supplemented config.

```
const supplementedConfig = supplement<Config>(config, ['a', 'b'])

/*
const supplementedConfig: Promise<{
    a: AdditionalConfig<string>;
    b: AdditionalConfig<string>;
    c: AdditionalConfig<string>;
}>
*/
```

That is great but in the above case I don't want to `c` to be wrapped.

I found a way by defined an additional generic type see example below.

```
declare function supplement2<T, K extends keyof T>(c: T, p: Array<K>): Promise<AddAdditionConfig<T, K>>

const supplementedConfig2 = supplement2<Config, 'a' | 'b'>(config, ['a', 'b'])

/*
const supplementedConfig2: Promise<{
    a: AdditionalConfig<string>;
    b: AdditionalConfig<string>;
    c: C;
}>
*/
```

But ideally, I wouldn't want to define additional generic type but rather being able to infer that from the values passed in the array e.g. `[ 'a', 'b' ]` which already is constrained by the first generic type.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking to build some type from the passed in parameters or are you looking to parse the passed parameters into one of several types?

Comment: I'm looking for a type from the passed value in parameters. (former one)

Comment: The compiler can infer specific types for type parameters if you don't specify them manually... doesn't `supplement2(config, ['a', 'b'])` do what you want?  If not, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @jcalz yes you are right, I think I've tried to make it more clever than it should be and by removing `<Config>` all works as expected. Thanks